# Why can't there be a direct absorption of a photon between Raman active states?

Tags: particle-physics, spectroscopy, raman-spectroscopy

My question pertains to the fundamental difference between Raman spectroscopy and IR spectroscopy. Simply put, the Raman active transitions correspond to a change in the polarizability of the molecule and IR transitions correspond to a change in the dipole moment of the molecule, both of which translates to a different rovibronic state. The IR transitions occur at specific 'absorption frequencies', while the Raman transitions occur via an intermediate excited state, where the difference in energy in the initial and final rovibronic states is given to the photon.

My question is - why can't the transition between Raman active states happen via a simple photon absorption of the resonant frequency, like it happens in IR spectroscopy. Why does the molecule have to be excited by the photon to an excited virtual state from the initial rovibronic state, then fall back to the final rovibronic state, instead of just absorbing a photon corresponding to the Raman wavenumber shift? I believe it is something tied to how a transition occurs for 'change in polarizability' compared to 'change in dipole moment', but needed some confirmation to what I am thinking (or trying to think)?